# macos standalone python

Tags: python, macos

Well I'm quite sure this is quite a stupid question but everything else seems to have failed so far(py2app and cx_freeze). So my question is basically:

On MacOS, from you python framework, is it possible to "select" some required files, that will 
then allow you to use "your" python elsewhere?

So shortly kind of an "export python" so you could get like an archive, and then on another pc just unzip and run that version of python, in a absolute path kind of way (eg. `~/Documents/PythonArchive/python` )?

regards,
Bogdan

Comment: Isn't that what `py2app` and `cx_freeze` do? Create a "bundle" that contains Python, so you don't need it installed in the target machine?  Your question isn't clear, more details?  What did you try? What failed?

Comment: I tried both but there are too many dependencies and both of them have different problems they can't handle. So my only "solution" if you could say that is to try and put all the dependencies myself in some folder, then distribute them with some python alongside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Check out [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

You give it the path to your python script and it analyzes all of your package imports, extracting any binary files that are needed and placing them into an archive. You can then just unzip the archive onto another OS X and it runs.

I've used it for a fairly complex python program, and it worked for me.